# What are these GCC/G++ parameters?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, parameters, g++

I've been using the UVa Online Judge to solve some programming challenges, and, when submitting my solutions, I'm told the judge will compile my code using the following parameters to GCC/G++ that I don't know: `-lm -lcrypt -pipe -DONLINE_JUDGE`.

What do they do? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Ashwin, it's not immediately apparent that the `lm` parameter is a different kind from `pipe`. The latter is a single word, whereas the former is actually `l` followed by the abbreviated name of a library. Also, of those four, `pipe` is the only one that actually shows up in the output of `gcc --help`. The rest require `-v`, and even after sifting through the many pages of output that gives you, you still won't find anything mentioning `lm` or `lcrypt`.

Comment: @Rob: But you find something like -l<...> (Don't know the exact documentation). So you could see that it is -l followed by something. (Same for -D<...>).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"-lm -lcrypt" specifies to link with the math and cryptography libraries - useful if you're going to use the functions defined in math.h and crypt.h.  "-pipe" just means it won't create intermediate files but will use pipes instead.  `"-DONLINE_JUDGE"` defines a macro called "`ONLINE_JUDGE`", just as if you'd put a "#define" in your code.  I guess that's so you can put something specific to the judging in your code in an "#ifdef"/"#endif" block.

Comment: "to include the math and cryptography libraries" should be "link to the math and cryptography libraries".

Comment: Just for completeness: -l<...> links the libraries "lib<...>.so*". So -lm links "libm.so*" and -lcrypt links "libcrypt.so*".